# Sql how to convert nest while loops to a CTE using two temp tables

Tags: sql, while-loop, common-table-expression, temp

I have one temp table that pulls from the Abstracting table for `dx codes` and Registration table for the account number.  It joins by the `VisitID` and the `dx codes` are in order by `DiagnosisUrn - #Visits`

I need to join it to the `Diag`Table.  The `dx codes`in this table are the primary ones for billing, in
order by `Transaction Number ID`  with the lowest number being the most primary.

In the end, for each `visit id , account id,`  I need to for the `Dx codes` to print out
like this example:

```
Account     ICD10   SequenceNumber  
AT000118    R06.00              1   
AT000118    I25.10              2   
AT000118    I65.23              3   
AT000118    E11.29              4   
AT000118    Z95.1               5   
AT000118    E11.65              6   
AT000118    E78.2               7   
AT000118    E78.1               8   
AT000118    E11.42              9
```

For this particular account (there are many others similar), all of the `dx` are in the `Visit` table
however only the first four are in `Diag` table with the proper `TransactionDiagnosisURN/DiagnosisURN/Sequence Number`

The While loops reorder the rest of `DX codes` that were in the visit temp table and adding them to the end of the ones in the `Diag` table with the result populating the `PBDxCodes` temp table.

It needs to run by date range - I've changed it to pull a few account numbers instead to try to work on
a CTE.  Using loops causes it to run an extremely long time and sometimes it just times out.

I'm getting a recursion error when trying to convert the query to CTE.  I have only used basic CTE in the past and it has been a while.

Below is the query using the while loop and then my attempt at trying to convert one loop to a CTE:
While loops:
DECLARE @NumofVisits AS INT
DECLARE @NumberofTxs AS INT
DECLARE @Looper AS INT
DECLARE @ThisVisitID AS VARCHAR(35)

--Get the VisitIDs to find Dx Codes

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Visits
   SELECT DISTINCT
        RAM.VisitID
       ,RAM.AccountNumber                                          
       ,ADX.DiagnosisCode_MisDxID 
       ,CAST(ADX.DiagnosisUrnID AS INT) AS ABSDxCode 
   INTO #Visits
   FROM livefdb.dbo.AbsAcct_Diagnoses ADX

   JOIN livefdb.dbo.RegAcct_Main AS RAM
       ON RAM.VisitID = ADX.VisitID
       AND RAM.SourceID = ADX.SourceID
       AND RAM.Facility_MisFacID NOT IN ('KK', 'JFJ','MPM')
       AND RAM.RegistrationType_MisRegTypeID  IN ('AMB','AMBR','BNV')

   LEFT JOIN livefdb.dbo.HimRec_Main AS HRM
       ON HRM.SourceID = RAM.SourceID
       AND HRM.PatientID = RAM.PatientID
   WHERE ADX.VisitID IN ('LE1-B20210114114749175', 'AT0-B20191211155403251'
                          ,'ID0-B20201201104450465','OM1-B20210107093907435'
                          ,'AT0-B20191205154143298','LE0-B20200716135146384'
                          ,'PC1-B20210111125154209','SV1-B20210112122435108'
                          ,'UB0-B20200915140417079','ID1-B20201222150226545'
                          )

   SET @NumofVisits = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT VisitID) FROM #Visits )

-- Create a table to hold Dx data for each visit
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #PBDxCodes
CREATE TABLE #PBDxCodes (
    EncounterRecordNumber VARCHAR(18),
    ICD10DiagnosisCode VARCHAR(15),
    SequenceNumber INT,
    )

-- Get the Diagnosis from BAR Transactions. The least transaction number is the Primary Charge
-- and the Diagnosis Codes are the Primary Diagnosis codes
WHILE @NumofVisits > 0
    BEGIN
       DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #UpdateDiag
       CREATE TABLE #UpdateDiag (
           DiagnosisUrnID  INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
           VisitID  VARCHAR(35),
           Diagnosis_MisDxID VARCHAR(50)
           )
       SET @ThisVisitID = (SELECT TOP 1 VisitID FROM #Visits)
       SELECT DISTINCT
          BATD.VisitID,
          BATD.TransactionNumberID,
          CAST(BATD.TransactionDiagnosisUrnID AS INT) AS TransactionDiagnosisUrnID,
          BATD.TransactionDiagnosis_MisDxID
       INTO #Diag
       FROM livefdb.dbo.BarAcct_TxnDiagnoses AS BATD
       WHERE BATD.VisitID = @ThisVisitID

       SET @NumberofTxs = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT TransactionNumberID) FROM #Diag)
       SET @Looper = 0

       WHILE ( @NumberofTxs > @Looper)
          BEGIN
             INSERT INTO #UpdateDiag(VisitID, Diagnosis_MisDxID)
             SELECT
                VisitID,
                TransactionDiagnosis_MisDxID
                FROM #Diag
                WHERE TransactionNumberID = 
                   (CASE WHEN 1 = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT TransactionNumberID) FROM #Diag)
                         THEN (SELECT TOP 1 TransactionNumberID FROM #Diag )
                         ELSE (SELECT MIN(TransactionNumberID) FROM #Diag)
                    END)
                    AND TransactionDiagnosis_MisDxID NOT IN (SELECT Diagnosis_MisDxID FROM #UpdateDiag)
                    ORDER BY TransactionDiagnosisUrnID
          
           DELETE FROM #Diag WHERE TransactionNumberID = (SELECT MIN(TransactionNumberID) FROM #Diag)
           SET @Looper = @Looper + 1
      END
-- Are there Diagnosis in Abstracting that are not in BAR
      INSERT INTO #UpdateDiag(VisitID, Diagnosis_MisDxID)
         SELECT
            VisitID,
            DiagnosisCode_MisDxID
         FROM #Visits
         WHERE #Visits.VisitID = @ThisVisitID
         AND #Visits.DiagnosisCode_MisDxID NOT IN (SELECT Diagnosis_MisDxID FROM #UpdateDiag)
         ORDER BY #Visits.ABSDxCode

-- Add this visit to the temp table holding final results
      INSERT INTO #PBDxCodes (EncounterRecordNumber,SequenceNumber,ICD10DiagnosisCode,SourceSystem)
         SELECT DISTINCT
            #Visits.AccountNumber AS EncounterRecordNumber,
            #UpdateDiag.DiagnosisUrnID AS SequenceNumber,
            #UpdateDiag.Diagnosis_MisDxID AS ICD10DiagnosisCode
         FROM #UpdateDiag
         INNER JOIN #Visits ON #UpdateDiag.VisitID = #Visits.VisitID
      
       DELETE FROM #Visits WHERE VisitID = @ThisVisitID
       SET @NumofVisits = @NumofVisits - 1
       DROP TABLE #Diag, #UpdateDiag
   END

SELECT * FROM #PBDxCodes 
WHERE EncounterRecordNumber='AT0001184503'
ORDER BY EncounterRecordNumber, SequenceNumber
DROP TABLE  #Visits, #PBDxCodes


CTE Attempt:
DECLARE @NumofVisits AS INT
DECLARE @NumberofTxs AS INT
DECLARE @Looper AS INT
DECLARE @ThisVisitID AS VARCHAR(35)

--Get VisitID,Account Nos and Dx in Abstracting.
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Visits
SELECT DISTINCT
    RAM.VisitID
    ,RAM.AccountNumber
    ,ADX.DiagnosisCode_MisDxID
    ,CAST(ADX.DiagnosisUrnID AS INT) AS ABSDxCode
INTO #Visits
FROM livefdb.dbo.AbsAcct_Diagnoses ADX
JOIN livefdb.dbo.RegAcct_Main RAM
    ON ADX.SourceID=RAM.SourceID
    AND ADX.VisitID=RAM.VisitID
    AND RAM.Facility_MisFacID NOT IN ('KK', 'JFJ','MPM')
    AND RAM.RegistrationType_MisRegTypeID  IN ('AMB','AMBR','BNV')
WHERE ADX.VisitID IN ('AT0-B20191211155403251','LE1-B20210114114749175')

SET @NumofVisits = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT VisitID) FROM #Visits);

WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT 
        V.ABSDxCode
       ,@NumofVisits AS n
       ,V.VisitID 
       ,V.DiagnosisCode_MisDxID
    FROM #Visits V
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
       C.ABSDxCode
      ,C.n+1
      ,V.VisitID AS VisitID
      ,V.DiagnosisCode_MisDxID
    FROM CTE C
    INNER JOIN #Visits AS V ON V.VisitID=C.VisitID
    )
    SELECT C.ABSDxCode, C.DiagnosisCode_MisDxID
    FROM CTE C
    WHERE C.n=(SELECT MAX(n) FROM CTE WHERE ABSDxCode=C.ABSDxCode)
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using. Can you also add the full recursion error message you get (edit the question, don't add additional information as comments)